# Qsettings able to store value only once?

Tags: c++, qml, qsettings

I am using Qsetting to store the last used values. My code works for only one field. That means it only works once when I am applying the same logic for the second go round it doesnt do that.

**fileio.cpp**

```
#include "fileio.h"
#include <QSettings>
#include <QStandardPaths>
#include <QtAndroid>
#include <QtAndroidExtras/QAndroidJniObject>
#include <QAndroidJniEnvironment>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QDebug>

FileIo::FileIo(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(maxrpmChanged()), this, SLOT(writeSettings()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(rampupChanged()), this, SLOT(writeSettings()));
}
//for Maxrpm
void FileIo::setMaxrpm(const QString &a) {
    if (a != m_maxrpm) {
        m_maxrpm = a;
        emit maxrpmChanged();
    }
}
QString FileIo::getMaxrpm() const {return m_maxrpm;}

//for Filename
void FileIo::setFilename(const QString &a) {

    if (a != m_filename) {
        m_filename = a;
        emit filenameChanged();
    }
}
QString FileIo::getFilename() const {return m_filename;}

//for Rampup
void FileIo::setRampup(const QString &a) {
    if (a != m_rampup) {
        m_rampup = a;
        emit rampupChanged();
    }
}
QString FileIo::getRampup() const {return m_rampup;}



void FileIo::readSettings(const QString &temp)
{
    QString m_path ;
    QString m_filename;
    QSettings * p_settings;
    QSettings settings("BlueSparq","motorapp");
    m_path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::ConfigLocation) ;
    m_filename = temp ;
    p_settings = new QSettings(m_path + "/"+ m_filename,QSettings::IniFormat) ;
    setMaxrpm(p_settings->value("target_RPM",QString("900")).toString());
    qDebug() <<m_maxrpm;
    //for Rampup
    setRampup(p_settings->value("rampup","250").toString());
    qDebug() <<m_rampup;
}

void FileIo::writeSettings()
{
    QString m_path ;
    QSettings * p_settings;
    QSettings settings("BlueSparq","motorapp");
    m_path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::ConfigLocation) ;
    p_settings = new QSettings(m_path + "/"+ m_filename,QSettings::IniFormat) ;
    p_settings->setValue("target_RPM",m_maxrpm);
    qDebug() << m_rampup;
    p_settings->setValue("rampup",m_rampup);
    qDebug() << m_rampup;
    p_settings->sync();
}
```

**fileio.h**

```
#ifndef FILEIO_H
#define FILEIO_H
#include <QObject>

class FileIo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString maxrpm READ getMaxrpm WRITE setMaxrpm NOTIFY maxrpmChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString filename READ getFilename WRITE setFilename NOTIFY filenameChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString rampup READ getRampup WRITE setRampup NOTIFY rampupChanged)
public:
    explicit FileIo(QObject *parent = 0);

    //For MaxRPM
    void setMaxrpm(const QString &a);
    QString getMaxrpm() const;

    //For Filename
    void setFilename(const QString &a);
    QString getFilename() const;

    //For Ramup
    void setRampup(const QString &a);
    QString getRampup() const;

    Q_INVOKABLE void writeSettings();
    Q_INVOKABLE void readSettings(const QString &temp);

signals:
    void maxrpmChanged();
    void filenameChanged();
    void rampupChanged();



public slots:


private slots:


private:
    QString m_maxrpm;
    QString m_filename;
    QString m_rampup;

};


#endif // FILEIO_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtQuick>
#include "sertransclient.h"
#include "fileio.h"
QObject *object;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    //added now
    QQuickView view;

    QObject::connect((QObject*)view.engine(), SIGNAL(quit()), &app, SLOT(quit()));

    qRegisterMetaType<SerTransClient::BaudRate>("SerTransClient::BaudRate");
    qRegisterMetaType<SerTransClient::DataBits>("SerTransClient::DataBits");
    qRegisterMetaType<SerTransClient::Parity>("SerTransClient::Parity");
    qRegisterMetaType<SerTransClient::StopBits>("SerTransClient::StopBits");
    qRegisterMetaType<SerTransClient::FlowControl>("SerTransClient::FlowControl");
    qmlRegisterType<SerTransClient>("sertransclient", 1, 0, "SerTransClient");
    qmlRegisterType<FileIo>("fileIo", 1, 0, "FileIo");
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    view.show();
    object = view.rootObject();
    //



    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably it's because you're leaking `QSettings`' memory **and resources** in your functions, so the first call makes later ones fail, because of occupied file handle, or shomething.